# Export a style to JSON

Tags: ms-word, office-js, openxml

Is there a way to export a style to JSON? I see there is `importStylesFromJson`, but nothing for exporting styles.

Alternately, where can I find the full description of the JSON format supported by `importStylesFromJson`? I need to create a custom style that involves numbering and font formatting.

Use case: customer has provided a Word document containing a style that they want my add-in to inject into active document. But there is no obvious way of converting that style into a programmatic object and then call `importStylesFromJson` on that.

Comment: The Style class has a toJson() method. Is that any help?

Comment: @jonsson: I too had hoped it would do the thing, but unfortunately it doesn't. It is an override that is called when someone calls `JSON.stringify()` on this API object and doesn't return the style JSON that I could feed again for importing the style.

Comment: AFAICS if you get the Word style object and use style.toJSON() you get a Word.Interfaces.StyleData object (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.interfaces.styledata?view=word-js-preview ). What you need for importStylesFromJson is a *string*, so I suppose I'd use e.g. const styledata = JSON.stringify(style.toJSON()), make a string using e.g. '{"styles":[' + styledata + ']}' and use importStylesFromJson to import that, cf.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-preview#word-word-document-importstylesfromjson-member(1)...

Comment: ...so if that isn't close to what you need, I have probably misunderstood. BTW somewhere in your code you may need to distinguish between built-in styles and user-defined ones (I don't know what names you'll get with built-ins).